# Visualize data from MySQL database using spring- boot and chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I am trying to visualize data from MySQL database using chartjs.
My ajax call works as I can see data in web but chart does not get created.

My code:

Controller

```
public class Controller {
@Autowired
public MessageService messageService;
@Autowired
private MessageRepository messageRepository;


@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping("/getdatafromdevice")
@ResponseBody
public String getData(){
    List<Message> dataList = messageRepository.findByDeviceid("device");
    JsonArray jsonArrayTemperature = new JsonArray();
    JsonArray jsonArrayHumidity = new JsonArray();
    JsonArray jsonArrayDatetime = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    dataList.forEach(data->{
        jsonArrayTemperature.add(data.getTemperature());
        jsonArrayHumidity.add(data.getHumidity());
        jsonArrayDatetime.add(data.getDatetime());
    });
    jsonObject.add("temperature", jsonArrayTemperature);
    jsonObject.add("humidity", jsonArrayHumidity);
    jsonObject.add("datetime", jsonArrayDatetime);
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
}
```

Index html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Data Visualization</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    
    <body class="bg-dark py-5">
    
    <div  class ="col-md-8 offset-md-2 " >
        <div class="card" >
            <div  class="card-body">
                <h1 class="text-center" >Data visualization  <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="getChartData()">Update</button></h1>
            </div>
            <div  class="card-body">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/chart.js"></script>

</html>
```

My Javascript chart.js

```
function renderChart(data, labels) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'temperature',
                    data: data[0],
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255,55,57,0.4)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                },
                {
                    label: 'humidity',
                    data: data[1],
                    borderColor: 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 1)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                }
            ]
        },
           options: {
                   scales: {
                       yAxes: [{
                           ticks: {
                               suggestedMin: 10,
                               suggestedMax: 100
                           }
                       }]
                   }
               }
    });
}

function getChartData() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "getdatafromdevice",
        success: function (result) {

            var data = [];
            data.push(result.temperature);
            data.push(result.humidity);
            var labels = result.datetime;
            renderChart(data, labels);
        }
    });
}
```

When I run this application and click on update button I can see empty chart, but every time I click on button the query to database is made and I can see my data in web like this:

```
 {,…}
datetime: ["2020-11-24 00:56:47", "2020-11-24 00:56:49", "2020-11-24 00:56:51", "2020-11-24 00:56:53",…]
humidity: [76.2616924895041, 75.73237408531122, 60.699698473163515, 73.70654165965911, 70.5605763362542,…]
temperature: [29.640586322716434, 26.97390069384724, 30.577907168201307, 21.844004972230522, 25.05155360103929,…]
```

I dont know if I need to change something in controller or in javascript.
Maybe I am missing json.parse in getChartData function but as I ma beginner in chart js anad jquery I dont know how to do it. Any idea how to fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, in case someone pass by in need to create something similar.

Just add `dataType: 'json',`

the function now looks like this

```
    function getChartData() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "getdatafromdevice",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
    
            var data = [];
            data.push(result.temperature);
                data.push(result.humidity);
                var labels = result.datetime;
                renderChart(data, labels);
            }
        });
    }
```